# How to get the min value for the first two columns and the max value for the next two in a list of 4 columns in python?

Tags: python

As an example, from the data below -

```
A  B  C  D         
30 10 20 8
30  5 20 20
20 10 30 10
```

I need to get `[20,5,30,20]` where A,B,C,D are column names. I can't use pandas.

Comment: What format is the data in now?  NumPy array?  A list of lists?  A CSV file?

Comment: If you want the minimum values for a column shouldn't it return `[20, 5, 20, 8]`?

Comment: Its a 2-dimensional list (table)

Comment: Well I want the min from the rows in the first two columns and the max from the rows in last two columns

Comment: 2-dimensional lists don't have column names.

Comment: The first row is to be treated as column names

Comment: Hopefully the large number of clarifying comments is teaching you that you need to be much clearer in your question. In this example, you could have just provided the example data in a Python statement.  Ideally, your question should also include your attempt to solve it, and details of the issues that you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `min(list)` to get the minimum value across a list
- use `max(list)` to get maximum value across a list

```py
data = [
    [30, 30, 20],
    [10, 5, 10],
    [20, 20, 30],
    [8, 20, 10]
]

new_list = []

for i in range(4):

    if i < 2:
        new_list.append(min(data[i]))
    else:
        new_list.append(max(data[i]))

print(new_list)


# Output
# [20, 5, 30, 20]
```

I know using a map and lambda can be less verbose and cool looking. But as the author of the question is a python beginner, I am using a for loop and the append method.

Comment: That is not what I want. I am not looking for the min value across the list. I am looking for a min value across a column. Look at the example data and the solution I want

Comment: hi JMushiana please look at my updated answer. Hope it helps

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I am implementing it right now. But I am getting an IndexError: list index out of range. I think because actually my data is of 8 columns. I just used 4 in this question as an example. I think I could just give the index of the column instead of the column I want the min from in data (out of the 8 columns), it should work. right?

Comment: This is what I have now for the for loop. Still getting an IndexError: list index out of range. for r1 in range(8):
        
        if r1 > 3 and r1 < 6:
            rMin.append(min(mMin[r1]))
        elif r1 > 6 and r1 <= 7:
            rMin.append(max(mMin[r1]))

Comment: python has a zero based index

Comment: For example : lst = [ 2,3,4,5]
the max index is 3
lst[0] is 2 and lst[3] is 5

Comment: Yes. That I knew. I have accounted for that col 6 and 7 are actually the last two columns in the list of 8 columns that I want the max from

Comment: Can you please post the exact code that is giving you an error?
the columns must be lists within the `data`  list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221765/discussion-between-jmushiana-and-aahnik-daw).

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have a few answers. Here's another one but at a level that may be easy for someone new to python. I also try to do it first in the simplest way and then use more advanced syntax to get things done faster.

I am not sure how your data is stored. I am going to store your input into a string and process the string in this example.

In this example, I am going to use [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) and if you are new to this concept, please review the link I have shared.

```
data = '''A.      B.         C.    D.         
30     10          20    8
30     5           20    20
20     10          30    10'''

#first split the string into a list
rows = data.split('\n')

#define a dictionary to store the values from the rows
dict_list = {'A':[],'B':[],'C':[],'D':[]}

#final values will be stored into the min_list
min_list = []

#next break each item from the row into a list of values
row_items = [i.split() for i in rows[1:]]

#add each item from the row as elements into a dictionary
for each_row in row_items:
    dict_list['A'].append(int(each_row[0]))
    dict_list['B'].append(int(each_row[1]))
    dict_list['C'].append(int(each_row[2]))
    dict_list['D'].append(int(each_row[3]))

#iterate through the dictionary to get the min value for each key
for k,v in dict_list.items():
    min_list.append(min(v))

print ('minimum of each col :', min_list)
```

The output of this will be:

```
minimum of each col : [20, 5, 20, 8]
```

Alternate way to do this will be using a few list comprehension and zip function
Similar to list comprehension, if you are new to [zip function](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/), please use this link.

```
#first split the string into a list
rows = data.split('\n')
#next break each item from the row into a list of values
row_items = [i.split() for i in rows[1:]]

#convert the row_items into integers
row_int_items = [[int(x) for x in row_item] for row_item in row_items ]

#transpose the list from rows to columns
col_items = list(zip(*row_int_items))

min_list = [min(x) for x in col_items]

print ('items by each row   :', row_int_items)
print ('items by each col   :', col_items)
print ('minimum of each col :', min_list)
```

The output from the second example will be as follows:

```
items by each row   : [[30, 10, 20, 8], [30, 5, 20, 20], [20, 10, 30, 10]]
items by each col   : [(30, 30, 20), (10, 5, 10), (20, 20, 30), (8, 20, 10)]
minimum of each col : [20, 5, 20, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = [[30,30,20], [10, 5, 10], [20, 20, 30], [8, 20, 10]]
a_b_min_idx = [*map(lambda x: x.index(min(x)), [lst[0]]+[lst[1]])] * 2
res = [*map(lambda i, j: lst[i][j], [*range(0, len(lst))], a_b_min_idx)]
res
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand this. I am new in Python. what is *map and lambda?  do I have to import another module?

Comment: `map()` applies a function, in this case min, over every element in a list. In this case, as we have a nested list, min is applied over the inner list. The `*` unpacks the returned iterable (map) object into a list or tuple. In your case you want to unpack it into a list `[]`.

Comment: no you do not have to import another module.

Comment: Ok. But this will return the minimum from across the list. that is not what I want. I want min across the column A and minimum across column B and then same way max across column C and max across column D. Look at the example data in my question and the expected result

Comment: @JMushiana apologies I misunderstood, try now

Comment: @hello_friend, in your example, `lst` is already transposed. The original data is 4 columns and 3 rows. You may want to start from there and transpose it before you do min for each item. Also, if `lst` is already there, you don't need to do a lot of complicated lambda function. You can just do `[min(x) for x in lst]` to get to the answer

Comment: @JoeFerndz I had that answer initially (`[*map(lambda x: min(x), lst)]`) and I was told it was wrong.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I suspect your interpretation is incorrect too, this is not your fault, OP is unclear.

Comment: @hello_friend, thank you for the input. I hope the OP clearly articulates the question so the right level of help can be provided. For now, I am going to move on until further information is available.